# How to declare variables in stored procedure using Select statement in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I want to create a stored procedure in PL/SQL by declaring variable using a `Select` statement. How can I create this?

My stored procedure looks like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ValueFinders
(REGION1 IN VARCHAR2(32 Byte),CONFIG1 IN VARCHAR2(128 Byte))

DECLARE GROUP1 VARCHAR2(128 Byte);
BEGIN
SET GROUP1:= Select GROUP from PRODUCTINFO where REGION=REGION1 AND CONFIG=CONFIG1;

select * from DEAL where GROUP=GROUP1; 

END

exec ValueFinders('ASIA','ABC');
```

The above code is showing error to me. Please Help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `into GROUP1` make sure it returns one 1 row , and group has the same datatype, I also recommand as good practice to add an exception.

do it like this

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE ValueFinders
    (REGION1 IN VARCHAR2(32 Byte),CONFIG1 IN VARCHAR2(128 Byte))

    DECLARE GROUP1 VARCHAR2(128 Byte);
    BEGIN
   -- SET GROUP1:= Select GROUP from PRODUCTINFO where REGION=REGION1 AND CONFIG=CONFIG1;

Select GROUP into GROUP1 from PRODUCTINFO where REGION=REGION1 AND CONFIG=CONFIG1;

   -- select * from DEAL where GROUP=GROUP1; 

    END
```

Comment: But I want to select values from DEAL table too...How can this be possible.

Comment: in a procedure ( or block statement) when you do a `select` you should add(into) it in a variable , so for the second select you should add an into for the column , for example `select value into group2 from deal where group=group1` @AmitAgarwal

Comment: This error means you dont have a coloumn called config1 check your table structure and a replace config1 with a valid column name @AmitAgarwal